# has already or was already

Tags: past-tense, run-on-sentences

Which is the best way to write this sentence?

> This system was designed to study the effects of climate change and anthropogenic pollution on microbial communities under highly controlled conditions **and has already been** validated

or

> This system was designed to study the effects of climate change and anthropogenic pollution on microbial communities under highly controlled conditions **was already** validated

Thanks!

Comment: Your second version is missing an "and". As it stands, it can *only* mean that what's been "validated" is *anthropogenic pollution on microbial communities under highly controlled conditions*. But I assume you mean to say *this **system*** has been validated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*has been* implies the validation is still in effect.

If you use *was*, you might write:

> *The system was certified as producing valid results in 2007, and the certificate expired in 2011*.

Saying the system *was validated* doesn't prohibit something to happen later that invalidated it again.

Comment: I think OP's system has just been validated (and maybe certified too), and the OP wants to emphasize that. But the sentence is kinda a run-over anyway.