# has been taking or has taken too much of your spare time

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

This is an old question but I have not been satisfied by the answers given

As I buy many records from Australia, I have an Australian friend who collects all the records I have bought there (I live in France) Today I received an email from my friend, he wanted to know if he could send them now (as he had a lot). I answered "yes" and wrote:

I hope it **has not been taking/ has not taken** too much of your spare time."

Why does present perfect seem  to be  better in this case "has taken" :the activity is not over he is still  holding  the records until he pack and send them . Is it because I said yes and we can consider the activity of holding nearly over

Comment: *Taken* means all efforts were in the past. They are not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [has already or was already](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13932/has-already-or-was-already) The (negated) Present Perfect Continuous implies the writer is concerned the issue is ***still*** taking too much of addressee's time. The Simple Past version carries no such implication, and could therefore be used even if the activity finished long ago.

Comment: **has (not) been taking** indicates that he has been spending time continuously or intermittently over a period of time; whereas **has (not) taken** refers to the cumulative expenditure of time inasmuch as the past participle conveys the notion of completion.

Comment: My answer addresses all these issues. Why not look at it?

Comment: I have looked at it  but as it is ongoing action continuous should be better  but the other answer the one by James K  tells  me that there is no need for continuous here

Comment: You must be kidding. I said you can use either (depending on what you **want to stress** and that's **more information** than the other answer and applies in general to all uses of the present perfect versus present perfect continous.

Comment: @YvesLefol  You're approaching this backwards. It's not whether there's a "need" but what it is that you wish to express.  If you want to express the idea that this effort on his part has been ongoing you can use the continuous, and if you want to express the idea that the time spent has added up, you can use the simple perfect.

Comment: There is a need for it, if you are worried about the amount of **continuous effort** your friend made for you, not just the fact that he made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Either one is OK depending on the meaning you wish to convey*. The *difference* between the two is *emphasis* as regards spending time on this.

1. "I hope this [better than it here] has not taken too much of your spare time".

At the time of speaking, now, in the present, you hope that from the time the person started in the past (but **not** defining when exactly in the past **such as** three weeks ago), that not too much of their time has been spent on this.
VERSUS

2. "I hope this has not been taking too much of your spare time".

Likewise, at the time of speaking, now, in the present, you hope that from the time the person started in the past (but **not** defining when exactly in the past **such as** three weeks ago) that not too much time of their time has been spent doing this **as an ongoing activity** up to this moment of speaking.

Compare: I hope this didn't take too much of your time. [at some defined and finished moment in the past. Passé composé in French.

So, 1) is past up to the moment of speaking and 2) is past up to the moment of speaking AND as a continuous activity up to this point in the present. 1) is past but undefined until now. 2) is past but undefined AND continous up to now (the time of speaking).

Answer (score 1):

The present perfect in English can be used for actions and states that continue up to the present.  This is often the case when the present perfect is paired with prepositional phrases headed by "since":  "I've worked at the bank since 2010."  You would use "been working" only if the job was seen as temporary.

So "This has taken up much of my spare time" could be used for a state that continues to the present.  There is no need to use a progressive "has been taking" in this situation.

It can be deceptive when comparing French and English, as both have a "past tense" that is formed by combining a form of the verb "have" with a past participle, the meanings of the "perfect aspect" in English and the *passé composé* are quite different.  The *passé composé* is mostly used for actions that are completed.  The perfect aspect in English is for past events with a connection to the present.

Comment: so my question is why "there is no need to use a progressive" as it is ongoing action

Comment: @YvesLefol It is not necessarily an ongoing action. The use of one or the other **depends on what *you want to say***. Now, I have said that twice.

Comment: The present perfect just tells us that this is past without saying when. The action continues to the **time of speaking**.

Comment: but in my example it is ongoing action so only continuous should be permitted

Comment: so why do I have the choice between the two forms

Comment: That's English.  The various tenses and aspects overlap in meanings, and don't map in a simple one-to-one way to the tenses and aspects in French. Sometimes (as with the perfect versus perfect progressive aspect) the differences are subtle and in many situations you can choose either.

Comment: @YvesLefol You are now changing your question. This: "no you could be waiting a little longer before sending them" is grammatical but does not make sense. However, your friend could say: You could be waiting a little longer before I send them.

Comment: @YvesLefol  You ask a question, don't accept an answer and then  you come and ask a completely different question. If you have another question, please ask a separate question.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150679/discussion-on-answer-by-james-k-has-been-taking-or-has-taken-too-much-of-your-sp); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.